# Does the Brace maneuver work with Unarmed Strikes

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, melee-combat

The brace maneuver from Tasha's reads:

> When a creature you can see moves into the reach
> you have with the melee weapon you're wielding,
> you can use your reaction to expend one superiority
> die and make one attack against the creature, using
> that weapon. If the attack hits, add the superiority
> die to the weapon's damage roll.

Can I use this with an unarmed strike, or do I have to be wielding an actual weapon?

Answer (score 4):

#### You cannot wield an unarmed strike, so this does not work

The Brace Maneuver states:

> When a creature you can see moves into the reach you have with **the melee weapon you're wielding**, you can use your reaction to expend one superiority die and make one attack against the creature, using **that weapon** [...]

You cannot wield an unarmed strike. I come to this conclusion because the rules are written using natural language and if somebody told me they were wielding their head, foot, or hand, I would be very confused. However, there is a stronger argument to make:

#### Unarmed strikes are not weapons, so this does not work

Regardless of whether or not you can wield an unarmed strike, the feature requires a weapon at two different times and unarmed strikes are not weapons:

> [...] Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons). [...]

Because unarmed strikes are not themselves weapons, they cannot be used for the Brace Maneuver.

Comment: Although I doubt this is a balance issue and more an oversight with multi-classing. RAW, I don't disagree with you.

Answer (score 3):

**Unarmed strikes are not weapons**

The Combat section of the Player's Handbook explains unarmed strikes:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon Attack, you can use an Unarmed Strike: a punch, kick, head--butt, or similar forceful blow (**none of which count as weapons**). On a hit, an Unarmed Strike deals bludgeoning damage equal to 1 + your Strength modifier. You are proficient with your unarmed strikes.

So you can see that unarmed strikes are NOT considered weapons and therefore, strictly Rules As Written, are not a valid option for the Brace maneuver.